# Setting up a ssl server socket with signed certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate

I'm trying to make a simple server which listens on a port and authenticates with ssl. I have files

```
server.crt
server.key
my-ca.crt
```

obtained with a openssl tutorial (http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Apache/apache-SSL.html). `my-ca.crt` is my own CA certificate, `server.crt` contains the x509 server certificate (signed with my-ca.crt) and `server.key` is the corresponding private key.

I now don't know how to load these three files in c#; I have something like

```
serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2("server.crt", "secret_password");
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
```

which doesn't work (I get an

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.
```

)
but I have no clue how to add the `server.key` and/or `my-ca.crt`.

Answer (score 3):

To use `X509Certificate2` in the form

```
serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2("server.pfx", "secret_password");
```

you should save certificate in PKCS12 format. See http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-pkcs12 and http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html

Comment: i've tried to do it like this:
`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout "temp\signkey.key" -out "temp\signkey.key" -config "openssl.cfg"` and 
`openssl pkcs12 -export -out "temp\certificate.pfx" -in "temp\signkey.key" -name "NAME"` but the exception remains. Any idea?

Comment: @Christoph you need include the private key on export process as follow: `openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -in certificate.cer -inkey certificate.key -name "SSL stream
Certificate"` with `-inkey` parameter.